# RabbitMQ redeliver message to the same consumer that rejected it

Tags: rabbitmq

I have an queue and messages in it.  Also i have two consumer in separate processes. I take message by one, and decide that this message is not mine, and reject it with requeue flag. In documentation I found the next phrase "The server MUST NOT deliver the message to the same client within the context of the current channel". Is that mean that the rejected message should be deliver to another consumer or not?

Comment: Did you actually try this out to see what the behavior is?

Comment: Yes.  I have try,  i have two instances of one application with different configuration for consuming different messages, by design the message that does not meet the some condition on one instance should be rejected and  processed by another. But this is does not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there are a couple of things going on here that I'd like to touch on.

First, your question as to the behavior of RabbitMQ. The rule referenced above comes from the [AMQP-0-9-1 specification](https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf). As with most implementation of open specs, RabbitMQ is not fully-conforming. [This page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html) describes in precise detail exactly which portions of the specification are implemented, and where any deviations occur.

On that page, it stipulates that "No attempt is made to prevent redelivery to the same client." RabbitMQ lists this as a planned addition in a future release, but it has been planned for quite a few years now.

**Should Consumers Be Picky?**

The more important question is the one you haven't directly asked, but that is "should my consumer be picky about which messages from the queue it processes?

The answer to this is a definitive "no." One of the key design assumptions about message queues is that any consumer subscribed to the queue should be able to process any message in the queue. Thus, it should be considered proper design that all consumers attached to the queue are running identical code (same code base, same version). If not, you're going to have some serious problems with your application sooner or later.

Reject should only be used to tell the broker that there is a problem with a particular message.  If there is a problem with a particular consumer (e.g. loses connection to a database), it should not reject the message, but instead should close the connection, triggering redelivery to another, working consumer.  By design, messages that need to be processed by a specialized or different consumer should be deposited in a different queue.

Comment: The 'non-pickiness' of consumers seems like a very restrictive constraint.  This effectively means I cannot have an application design where only the consumer knows whether it is capable of processing a certain type of message, effectively forcing the publisher to know this and classify the messages accordingly.  Furthermore what you are suggesting means we shouldn't even use the correlation id to determine if a message is for us (as this is just one example of pickiness based on the message).  Is this not a bit extreme?

Comment: @Martin, you would use a topic exchange in that case.

Comment: Thanks @theMayer, indeed that's what I've gone for in the past but it wasn't a great fit for my problem.  I'm curious what you think about the correlation id issue?  Surely if we use a shared reply queue as suggested in the RMQ docs then we have to discriminate whether a message is for us and then you definitely don't want RMQ spamming you with messages you've rejected.

Comment: I don't know that a shared reply queue is a suggested approach. I usually set up my publishers with their own unique reply-to queue, whereby any message sent back to that publisher would go to the unique queue.

Comment: To elaborate on my comment from yesterday, all publishers know what type of message they are publishing. If there are characteristics of the message that make it unprocessable by some consumers, then you have a different *type* of message. Conversely, if some consumers cannot handle messages with certain data, then those consumers need to be reprogrammed such that they can. I can't imagine a scenario in a properly-designed architecture where the same message type might succeed on one consumer and fail on another if both are supposed to be able to consume it.